# How to download files from a web folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I have a web folder e.g. "http://www.myhost.com/software/" if I open this address in IE it show me all files which this folder have.
I want to download all files but I don't want to hard-code name of files. I know I can get the files with `webclient.DownloadFiles(@address,@filename)`. Is this possible to download all files or at least get the name of files from the web folder?

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum you can download the same file IE displays (note that this file is provided by your web server -- there is not a standard) and parse the HTML for the files yourself, e.g. using `webclient.DownloadFile("http://www.myhost.com/software/", @listfilename)`.

To access the files more "professionally", you'll need to see if the server also allows access via FTP or WebDAV because HTTP does not have a file "interface".